# Deploy Content on Private IP Address?

Tags: html, networking, browser, ip, portforwarding

I was reading about port forwarding which got me excited to try it myself.
But I'm stuck on the first step, given an html file how can I deploy it on my laptop's private ip address with custom port?

For example, imagine my laptop's ip is 10.0.0.4

Then when typing: 10.0.0.4:9011 in the browser I want to see the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Port forwarding would only be necessary if you want to make your laptop/server accessible outer your home network.

It is not only about port forwarding, you also need to install and run a server service like apache if you want to open that html file in a browser.

Additionally your laptop's public IP is probably not static. Almost all internet providers give you a dynamic IP for personal use. Which means that you need to use a different IP everyday to access that file.

However if you want to use that file only in your home network, then you still need a service like apache to host your file but you dont need a port forwarding + you can make your local IP static.

[Here is a useful blog to host a website on your pc](https://makeawebsitehub.com/host-website-computer/)

Comment: 1) "you can make your local IP static" This can only be done by contacting my carrier and paying money right? 2) "Which means that you need to use a different IP everyday to access that file." I don't agree, as long as I don't turn off the router it's the same ip...

Comment: 1) No you dont, you can set that via your router. However for making ur public IP static you need to pay money. Or you just register a domain and via DynDNS the domain gets updated everytime your IP changes

Comment: 2) It doesnt matter, whether you turn off your router or not. At least for Germany. Your connection to the carrier will be reset, in my case, it happens daily at 2-3 am, I lose internet for a few secs and then it is all good again

Comment: interesting, here you can keep it for years if you don't turn off the router. How they allow cutting the internet for few seconds? those may be so much critical in some situations.

Comment: @john indeed, well if your IP doesnt change, then consider that point not applied to you ^^